# Movie where a woman goes to a world not known to humanity or to some distant star system through a secret project

Tags: story-identification, movie

In an English movie I watched a long time back (perhaps at least 15 years back, not sure), they try to build a machine that acts as portal to another world, but they're not sure of how it will work. It looked like a secret project. In that a woman pilot (or scientist) enters, and reaches a place unknown to humanity. After sometime, she's back and a committee of senior officers question her on her experience. If I remember correctly she had gone to a world not known to humanity or to some distant star system.

I don't remember name of any character or the movie name, but it looked awesome. Does anybody know the name of the movie?

Comment: If *Contact* is the answer, I suggest checking out the novel by Carl Sagan. It’s better than the film.

Comment: The secret portal reminds me of Stargate but it was a military team, not a woman.

Comment: If the answer is Contact, I officially feel old ("a long time back", indeed! :-) )

Comment: This is likely not the answer whatsoever, but the part of the military being prevalent reminds me of this Twilight Zone episode ("The Wall") from the 80s: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734763/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

*[Contact](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(1997_American_film))* features a woman using a machine designed using instructions from an extraterrestrial message — the machine takes her to another world and upon her return she is interrogated by the military and politicians.

[Official Movie Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9C2cF3KvP8).

[Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWrWZaPnFzY) with Jodie Foster's character being questioned by Congress.

Comment: Jodie Foster plays the protagonist if that helps jog the memory.

Comment: That's the one I thought of when I saw the question, but according to my recollection the project in *Contact* wasn't secret.

Comment: If *Contact* is the right answer, this is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58547/14111

Comment: @user14111 The project wasn't a secret, but the backup facility was.

Comment: And Foster's reports of what happened were suppressed

Comment: Does this line ring a bell? "Number one rule of government spending...why buy one when you can get two for twice the price?"

Comment: Thank you everybody, I'm overwhelmed by answer, upvotes and comments. I think it should be contact, but one scene I remember is where few military officers were questioning/talkting to her after just after she came back, not congress. At least, I didn't watch movie till that scene. I'm searching (on youtube, my netflix doesn't have that movie) for that scene where few military officers/scientists question her just after the incident. If I can find that I'll confirm answer!

Comment: Notably, she's a scientist.  Not a pilot.  (Or a poet for that matter.  Notable line in the movie: "They should have sent a poet".)  Though she is strapped into a seat that looks like a cockpit, so maybe that's where the confusion came from.

Comment: @tiredandboreddev: She is definitely questioned by scientists immediately after she goes through the machine.  There is a very brief clip of that scene (video only, no audio) at 9:55 in [this video](https://youtu.be/yqtmkqzmlBo?t=595).

Comment: I was finally able to watch the movie, and have accepted Contact as the correct as answer for two reasons 1. There was a short interrogations (though not clear), and 2.  I could reconnect with the beach scene. Thanks everyone!!